# R: split dataframe into 3 parts

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I am trying to divide the dataframe into 3 parts.(4352 rows)
I tried `split(df,1:3)` and it does the job but when I try view the split df, it gives an error.

```
splitdf<-split(df, f = rep_len(1:3, nrow(df)   ))   
View(splitdf)
```

> Error in View : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1451, 1450*

Am I missing anything?

Comment: `View` is for viewing rectangular objects, so before viewing it attempts to coerce the object to a data frame. you will get the same error if you try `as.data.frame(splitdf)` which is attempting to put each of the 3 list elements into a single column (and the length of the list elements is not the same -- `sapply(splitdf, nrow)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the `length.out` argument in `rep`

```
split(df, rep(1:3, length.out = nrow(df), each = ceiling(nrow(df)/3)))
```

Comment: I did split(df, as.numeric(gl(nrow(df), nrow(df)/3, nrow(df)))), but it split the df in 4 parts of 1450,1450,1450 and 2.

Comment: Using 3 instead of nrow(df)/3, it gave me 1450 groups of 3 rows

Comment: it still didnt work becuase 4 groups were created. I think the n(row) is not divisible by 3 which is giving me a hard time

Comment: @DipeshSurana Suppose you have 10 rows, and you want 3 equal sized datasets, do you take the last row?

Comment: My bad. I didnt mention it , I need 3 parts and not equal sized. so 4352 rows into 1450,1450,1452.

Comment: @DipeshSurana  In that case, use the `length.out` argument in `rep`

Comment: @DipeshSurana  Or you can specify `split(df, rep(1:3, c(1450, 1450, 1452)))`