# Is there an easy way to split an dataset in x groups?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I wonder if there is an easy way to split an R dataset / data.frame into e.g. 10 groups of the same size? I have a dataset which is ordered by a response variable. I want to analyze the avaerage response rates for 10 groups, descending in response value.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Try `split()` in R.

Comment: `split(iris, sample(rep(seq(10), nrow(iris) / 10)))` or more usually, `split(iris, iris$Species)`

Comment: hi @alistaire, this works just fine! Thank you!

Comment: Related: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149250/split-data-into-n-equal-groups), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41701064/r-split-dataframe-into-3-parts), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139708/split-data-frame-into-rows-of-fixed-size).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be using the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/).
The function **group_by()** lets you group your dataframe by one or more variables and then use the **summarise()** function to perform specific task on each group.

An example:

```
library(tidyverse)
Result <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
 summarise(MeanMPG = mean(mpg)) %>% arrange(MeanMPG)
Result
```